# Proof that a given commutator subgroup is a subgroup of another group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to understand the proof of the following lemma.

> **Lemma:** The commutator subgroup of $F_{i+1}$ is a subgroup of the group $\langle x_1, \ldots, x_{i-1}\rangle = g^{-1}F_{i-1}g$, where
>    $(1 \leq i \leq t-2)$.
>
> **Proof:** Provided that $1 \leq i \leq t-2$, the groups $F_i = \langle x_0, \ldots, x_{i-1} \rangle$ and $g^{-1}F_ig = \langle x_1,
>  \ldots, x_i \rangle$ are different, and they are both of index two in
>    $F_{i+1}$, and consequently normal in $F_{i+1}$. Thus their
>    intersection $\langle x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1} \rangle = g^{-1}F_{i-1}g$ is
>    normal in $F_{i+1}$, and the quotient group $F_{i+1}/(g^{-1}F_{i-1}g)$
>    is Abelian, since it has order 4. Hence the commutator subgroup of
>    $F_{i+1}$ is contained in $g^{-1}F_{i-1}g$.

The proof is from "Algebraic Graph Theory" by Biggs (1974), and is shown on page 123 (if anybody happens to have the book). Although the subject is algebraic graph theory, I am quite sure that the proof relies on regular group theory.

**Edit:** Here are some more details, which in retrospect were important

First, the group $F_i$ is defined as: $F_i = \langle x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_{i-1} \rangle$. There is the following relation between $g$ and $x_i$
$$x_i = g^{-i}x_0g^i$$

The elements $x_i$ are involutions, that is $x_i = x_i^{-1}$. The order $|F_i| = 2^i$. This (as mentioned by Jack, this gives immediately that the index of $F_i$ in $F_{i+1}$ is 2, since $|F_{i+1}/F_i| = |F_{i+1}|/|F_i|$. The group $F_0$ is the identity.

**Current status:** At this point, I am almost through the proof, and currently the only thing which I do not understand is the sentence:

> Provided that $1 \leq i \leq t-2$, the groups $F_i = \langle x_0, \ldots, x_{i-1} \rangle$ and $g^{-1}F_ig = \langle x_1,
>  \ldots, x_i \rangle$ are different

I do not see why this is true, and I do not see why it is important. If somebody can answer that sub-question, I will mark the answer as correct.

Comment: Most of the proof requires knowing something about these groups $F_i$.  However, the order 4 part is a little silly. If $N$ has index 2 in $G$, then $N$ is normal in $G$, and $G/N$ is abelian so $N$ contains the commutator subgroup.  If $M$ is also a subgroup of index 2, then $M$ also contains the commutator subgroup. If both $M$ and $N$ contain something, then $M \cap N$ contains it too.

Comment: Some things that are false in general: I see no reason for $F_i$ to have index 2 in $F_{i+1}$, and there is no reason that $\langle X \rangle \cap \langle Y \rangle = \langle X \cap Y \rangle$.

Comment: How are $F_i$ and $g$ defined ?

Comment: I have added some additional information to the question.

Comment: Cool, pretty sure the index 2 and intersection claims are still false (in other words, you'll need even more information about the groups than what is in this question so far).

Comment: If you can point me in the right direction, I can try to add some more details. One this which I can note, is that $G = \langle g,x_0 \rangle$. Edit: Which does not really help I guess, since the question does not mention anything about $G$.

Comment: Is $F_0=1$ the identity? If so you can see that you need some commutation relations between the $x_i$ by taking $x_1=(1,2)$, $x_2=(2,3)$ and $g=(1,2,3)$.  Then $G=S_3$ is the symmetric group on 3 elements, $F_0=1$, $F_1=S_2$, $F_2=S_3$, and $[F_2,F_2] = A_3$ is not contained in any conjugate of $F_0$ or even of $F_1$.

Comment: Oh ho, knowing the order of $F_i$ is very good.  That proves the index 2 thing immediately, and I suspect in this case the intersection thing.

Comment: $F_0$ is the identity.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3763/discussion-between-utdiscant-and-jack-schmidt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this post has been here, I have figured out the last details of the proof. Below is my new expanded proof:

> Provided that $1 \leq i \leq t-2$, the groups $F_i = \langle x_0, \ldots, x_{i-1} \rangle$ and $g^{-1}F_ig = \langle x_1, \ldots, x_i \rangle$ are different. This is true, since if they were equal, the group $F_i$ would include $x_i$, which would make it equal to $F_{i+1}$, but we know that the order of $F_i$ and $F_{i+1}$ is not the same.
>
> Since $|F_i| = 2^i$, we have that
>   $
> |F_{i+1} / F_i| = \frac{|F_{i+1}|}{|F_i|} = \frac{2^{i+1}}{2^i} = 2
> $
>   and the same holds for $g^{-1}F_ig$. Thus both $F_i$ and $g^{-1}F_ig$ are index 2 in $F_{i+1}$. Since a subgroup of index 2 is normal, we then have that $F_i$ and $g^{-1}F_ig$ are normal subgroups in $F_{i+1}$. Since the intersection of two normal subgroups is also a normal subgroup, this gives us, that their intersection $\langle x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1} \rangle = g^{-1}F_{i-1}g$ is normal in $F_{i+1}$. Again using the order of $F_i$, we see that the quotient group $F_{i+1}/(g^{-1}F_{i-1}g)$ has order 4, and is therefore Abelian. At last, we use that for a group $G$, the quotient group $G/N$ is Abelian, iff the commutator subgroup of $G$ is a subset of N. This gives that $F_{i+1}/(g^{-1}F_{i-1}g)$ is Abelian -- and shows that the commutator subgroup of $F_{i+1}$ is contained in $g^{-1}F_{i-1}g$.